# Android bottomsheet that can swipe bottom/up and left/right

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, bottom-sheet

I want to implement a behavior where user can swipe view up/bottom and left/right also. Currently in a bottomsheet we can drag view upward and downward. And In a viewpager we can swipe view left to right. But we cant do both simultaneously. I want mix of both bottomsheet and viewpager. This behavior was implemented in an older version of google maps app.

Comment: I am also searching for this but not found any solutions on internet I don't have this much time to write own customization.